# Getting problem in SQL installation. Error messages are coming

Tags: sql-server, installation

I am getting some problems with SQL installation. first SQL 2008 was installed on my computer.
I uninstalled it on installed SQL 2014. After installation, although it was running fine, I was not able to open the SQL files directly. Due to that reason, I again uninstalled it with the whole process and trying to install it again and again but this error is coming-
"[error message] to continue, select a feature to install. if all features are already selected, these features are installed. you cannot add additional features." So it's becoming a dead-end for me, so can someone help me with this. I am attaching a screenshot of the error message below.

[Here is the image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sajnB.png)r.com/tBkri.png

Comment: Why do you want to open the SQL files directly? Your entire interaction with them should be through SQL Server.

Comment: Try it with run as administrator